# run multiple commands in oneline (like in linux **date && ls**) in **HP iLO3 ssh console

Tags: ssh, hp, ilo

i want to run multiple commands in oneline (like in linux **date && ls**) in **HP iLO3 ssh console**, but it (**&&**) not works. How i can do it? I not found it in [documentation](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02237707.pdf)
i want run 2 commands by sh script:

```
cd /map1/firmware1 && show /map1/firmware1
```

but it not works
i tryed to run uname -a command:

```
</>hpiLO-> uname -a

mgmt-proc mpsim 1_0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work.
The documentation that you linked doesn't contain any reference to "&&".
The iLO isn't running Linux, or bash, so I wouldn't assume that those conventions would work the same way.

See this answer over in SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540566/ilo3-multiple-ssh-commands

If you try using one of the scripting interfaces to connect to iLO, rather than doing it from the iLO command interface directly, you'll have access to better scripting tools.